# PHP WordPress Как удалить и заново прицепить фильтр из плагина в чайлд теме

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть родительская тема + плагин к ней. В плагине есть шаблон, который отвечает за вывод табов в личном кабинете, пример кода:

```
$tabs = array(
    'my-courses' => esc_html__('My Courses', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
    'my-quizzes' => esc_html__('My Quizzes', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
    'my-orders'  => esc_html__('My Orders', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system'),
);

if (STM_LMS_Subscriptions::subscription_enabled()) $tabs['my-memberships'] = esc_html__('My Memberships', 'masterstudy-lms-learning-management-system');

$tabs = apply_filters("account-private-parts-tabs", $tabs);

$active = 'my-courses';
?>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <?php foreach ($tabs as $slug => $name): ?>
        <li role="presentation" class="<?php echo ($slug == $active) ? 'active' : '' ?>">
            <a href="#<?php echo esc_attr($slug); ?>" data-toggle="tab">
                <?php echo wp_kses_post($name); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Мне нужно в чайлд теме убрать фильтр из плагина и создать новый фильтр, где я переопределю шаблоны табов. Как можно это реализовать? Пробовал в functions.php добавить:

```
remove_filter("account-private-parts-tabs", array($tabs));
```

Но фильтр не убирается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю вашу задачу то выхотите поменять табы. Удалять вам ничего не надо, а нужно просто правильно использовать фильтры:

```
add_filter( 'account-private-parts-tabs', 'my_account_private_parts_tabs' );
function my_account_private_parts_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['my-orders'] ); // Удаляем вкладку My Orders.
    $tabs['my-tab'] = 'My tab'; // Добавляем вкладку My tab.

    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: Всё верно, сработало, спасибо. Но есть один момент, дальше в коде идёт див, и в нём форычём (foreach ($tabs as $slug => $name): ) прогоняются все шаблоны  <?php STM_LMS_Templates::show_lms_template('account/private/parts/tabs/' . $slug); ?> Вот мне нужно эту директорию заменить на свю

Comment: Смотрите как работает STM_LMS_Templates::show_lms_template. Скорее всего директорию можно переопределить в теме

Comment: ну там идёт класс, я в чайлде от него отэкстендил свой класс и использовал его в некоторых моментах, но show_lms_template там идёт как статичный метод, т.е. я не смогу его поменять никак по идее

Comment: "Объявление свойств и методов класса статическими позволяет обращаться к ним без создания экземпляра класса. Свойство класса, объявленное как статическое, не может быть доступно посредством экземпляра класса (но статический метод может быть вызван"

Понял

Comment: Я поклацал там по методам и там есть:   $lms_template = apply_filters('stm_lms_template_file', STM_LMS_PATH, $template_name) . $template_name; Тут вы точно так же через add_filter можете поменять шаблон